# Retorno JSON dando como undefinided no jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Tenho essa requisição ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "retorno.php",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data["nome"]);
    },
    error: function(erro){
        alert(erro);
    }
})
```

E o arquivo retorno.php:

```
<?php 
    $teste=array();
    $teste["nome"]="nometeste";
    $teste["idade"]="aa";
    $a=json_encode($teste);
    echo $a;
?>
```

O retorno.php resulta em:

```
{
    "nome":"nometeste",
    "idade":"aa"
}
```

Mas no `jQuery`, dentro da requisição `ajax`, tanto o `data["nome"]` quanto o `data["idade"]` retornam `undefinided`.
O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A navegação pelo objeto JSON se dá com ponto, ou seja, para acessar o valor de `nome`, você deve usar `data.nome`.

Além disso, sugiro explicitar que você espera um JSON como retorno, com o parâmetro `dataType: 'json'`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "retorno.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       alert(data.nome);
    },
    error: function(erro){
       alert(erro);
    }
})
```

Comment: É irrelevante usar `data["nome"]` ou `data.nome`,  _"A navegação pelo objeto JSON se dá com ponto"_ não é 100% correto. O problema aqui era acrescentar `dataType: 'json'`, para o ajax retornar um objeto.